# DeprecationWarning: save is deprecated. Use insert_one or replace_one instead

Tags: replace

I have variable site_id = "31.12401" and I want to remove dot.
Here is my code:

```
try:
    cursor = db.tank.find({"site_id": {"$regex": "\."}}).limit(100)
except Exception as e:
    print ("exception", type(e), e)

for doc in cursor:
    doc["site_id"] = doc["site_id"].replace(".","") 
    db.tank.save(doc)
```

It works but I have warning "ipykernel_launcher.py:12: DeprecationWarning: save is deprecated. Use insert_one or replace_one instead"

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `monogoengine` and `pymongo` to the latest revision by issuing:

```
pip3 install -U mongoengine pymongo
```

Unfortunately, mongoengine `update` method still yields the deprecation warning propagated from pymongo.